# slide transition navigate html pages uiwebview

Tags: ios, uiwebview, uiviewanimationtransition

Hello everyone i have a uiwebview which is loading a website. So the website has links on click which will open a different page. My question is how to add a slide transition when navigating from 1 page to another? Like kCATransitionFromLeft ? Or can i inject javascript or use css transition. assuming that I don't want to change the HTML code of the website.

Comment: for that you need query mobile

Answer (score 0):

The following link  good tutorial for integration

http://www.htmlgoodies.com/html5/tutorials/introduction-to-jquery-mobile.html#fbid=AECboCFnPD-

And regarding animation between html page

http://view.jquerymobile.com/1.3.2/dist/demos/widgets/transitions/#Pagetransitions

And using CSS3  also we can make animation  for that following link will help you

http://davidwalsh.name/css-flip